# Can a WCF data contract be recursive? For example a binary tree? Is there a difference with ASMX services in supporting recursive data structures?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, soa

In SOA I believe that the wsdl does not support recursive data types but I saw some examples where the proxy actually works. Anybody knows more about this?

Answer (score 2):

Recursive type definitions are allowed and even cyclic object graphs are allowed and serializable.  However, in order to keep from running out of stack space while serializing and deserializing, you'll need to create a custom behavior overriding the CreateSerializer method and setting the preserveObjectReferences parameter to true when its creating a DataContractSerializer.  See James Kovacs' [blog](http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/GoingAroundInCirclesWithWCF.aspx) for more.

Comment: Thank you Travis, this is the answer that I was looking for. Very good blog indeed

Answer (score 0):

Please define what you mean by recursive. The following is a valid XML Schema for use in a WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Node" type="NodeType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="NodeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Node" type="NodeType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Let's say you have something like this:
[DataContract]
public class Tree{
[DataMember]
 public Tree Left{
get;set;
}
[DataMember]
public Tree Right{
get;set;

[DataMember]
public String Data{
get;set;
}
}

}

Comment: in SOA , isn't it true that recursive data types are not supported?

Comment: @Neo: I've never heard that. If you can find a citation, please post it.